# How to find which side was collided with using SAT

Tags: collision-detection, separating-axis-theorem

I am using Separating Axis Theorem to check whether two polygons (player and object) intersect. I want to make the player bounce off the object, but to do this I need the side (from which I will calculate the angle) that the player collided with.

How can I get this from my SAT function?

Answer (score 0):

When you calculate all your axis, in fact you get all the normals and so the sides.

You have to rotate all your axis by 90° an save whichpair of vertex give you the axis /normal.

So if the minimal overlap is on your axis[x], the side has a normal vector of rotate(axis[x],90).

And you have to project the vector between centers of yours objects on the  minimal overlap axis, if the result is under 0 you have to take the opposite normal and vertex associated.

Note : In the case when you calculate your axis, left to right, otherwise you have to use -90°